# fixing error 1241 operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I am very new to mysql and when i try my query it always gives and error 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s)

what gives off this error?

here is my block of query:

```
select g.id,
(select count(*), sum(sales)
FROM transactions t1 
where t1.customernumber between g.from_customernumber and g.to_customernumber)
from customer_groups g
```

Comment: `(select count(*), sum(sales)
FROM transactions t1 
where t1.customernumber between g.from_customernumber and g.to_customernumber)` what's your expected result of this?

Comment: `SELECT 
    g.id,
    result
FROM
    customer_groups g` this statement is simpler, so you can see the result shoule be a column right?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not allow getting more than one column from a subquery, used within `SELECT` clause. You can rather shift your subquery to `FROM` part as a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and join to the `customer_groups` table accordingly.

Use the following instead:

```
SELECT g.id, 
       dt.count, 
       dt.total_sales
FROM customer_groups AS g 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT customernumber, 
         COUNT(*) as count, 
         SUM(sales) as total_sales 
  FROM transactions AS t1 
  GROUP BY customernumber
) AS dt 
  ON dt.customernumber BETWEEN g.from_customernumber AND 
                               g.to_customernumber
```